# using jquery find('.classname') not working for locating TD elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am traversing the divs on my page and looking up child elements using find and supplying a classname

select elements and input elements are located, but the 3 TDs I am trying to find are returning nothing

Here is the code snippet

```
        $.each($(".ccypair"), function(index, element) {
            var elements = {
                selectElement   : $(element).find('.selectstyle'),
                inputElement    : $(element).find('.inputstyle'),
                tdElement1      : $(element).find('.decayTime'),
                tdElement2      : $(element).find('.price.bidprice'),
                tdElement3      : $(element).find('.price.offerprice')
            };
        });
```

Now the first two `find()` lines work fine, but the three `tdElement` ones below resolve to nothing.  Anyone able to tell me where I am going wrong.  I suspect for TD I need to have a different selector?

Apologies here is the html

```
   <div class="ccypair" id="ccypairdiv_0">
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="top currency"><select class="ccypairselect"/></td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="top volume"><input class="ccypairvolume" type="text" value="1m" autocomplete="off"/></td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="decaytime">00h:00m:00s</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="price bidPrice">---.---</td>
                    <td colspan="3" class="price offerPrice">---.---</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="ccypair" id="ccypairdiv_1">
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="top currency"><select class="ccypairselect"/></td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="top volume"><input class="ccypairvolume" type="text" value="1m" autocomplete="off"/></td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="top decaytime">00h:00m:00s</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="price bidPrice">---.---</td>
                    <td colspan="3" class="price offerPrice">---.---</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some html that this will fail on for testing purposes?

Comment: Can you show some sample HTML from the table?

Comment: Why not `$('.ccypair').each(function(index, element)` (just an observation, not a solution)?

Comment: The code you posted is working [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/4n09jc7b/). The problem must be in your `html`, which you for some reason are not providing.

Answer (score 1):

First check if your jQuery is loading with the $, the try this

```
//think about structure, it makes your code more legible

$(".ccypair").each(function(index) {
    var element = $(this); //each .ccypair found
    var elements = {
        selectElement   : element.find('.selectstyle'),
        inputElement    : element.find('.inputstyle'),
        tdElement1      : element.find('.decayTime'),
        tdElement2      : element.find('.price.bidprice'),
        tdElement3      : element.find('.price.offerprice')
    };
});
```

cheers

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that jQuery has been loaded

Comment: We are just talking semantics now.  Making the code look neater does not solve my problem.  I agree yours does make it more readable, but your post does not help in any way

Comment: @juckky ok its fare.. I guess the problem should be the class names
html: class="top decaytime"
js: find('decayTime')

Answer (score 0):

As always a back to basics approach worked.  A simple typo was the root cause here.  Apologies

On that note.  Does jQuery provide a flag so that rather than failing to locate an element and failing silently it will print out an error message.  This would be really helpful?